# Counting the occurrences of the string

Tags: text-processing

As input, we have some ids which are strings. How do we calculate what identifier has appeared most frequently and how many times?

#### Example

Input:

```
cat 
dog 
cat
dog
dog
dog 
dog 
fly
spider
spider
cat
cat
```

Output:

```
dog 5
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the commands  `sort` & `uniq -c` to count the occurrences of all the strings like this:

```
$ sort sample.txt | uniq -c
      4 cat
      5 dog
      1 fly
      2 spider
```

If you just want the one string "dog" you can use `grep` either before or after.

*after*

```
$ sort sample.txt | uniq -c | grep dog
      5 dog
```

*before*

```
$ grep dog sample.txt  | uniq -c
      5 dog
```

#### How it works

The command `uniq -c` will count all the unique strings that it's presented, but the list needs to be in sorted order first. Hence why we use the `sort` command prior to doing the tally.

The command `grep` is for selecting things in the output that are of interest. You can thing of `grep` as a filter that can act either inclusively or exclusively depending on what you want from the output.

The `sort` command can sort data based on rules. In this case we're letting it behave in its default mode, so it's sorting the data based on an alphanumeric set of sorting rules.

Comment: I almost got it, well played

Comment: For small file sizes it doesn't matter, of course, but I guess you agree that it's kind of crazy in the general case to sort a file in order to count entries. Especially if the sorting is used for the output formatting only...

Comment: @HaukeLaging - this appears to be homework, so the approach I suggested would be the aim of the instructor (I'm guessing) to solve this Q. But for larger files yes you're absolutely right.

Comment: You'll need to force the locale to C for both `sort`  and `uniq` for that to  work properly. Try `printf '%s\n' ① ② | sort | uniq -c` in a typical GNU system deployment for instance.

Comment: Dang, slm. I saw the question and thought `uniq -c`! Oh well, well done.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for one string only:

```
grep -cxF dog
```

or

```
echo "dog: $(grep -cxF dog)"
```

An efficient solution for a complete list:

```
> awk '{a[$0]++}; END {for (val in a) print val ": " a[val];}' file
spider: 2
cat: 4
fly: 1
dog: 5
```

Comment: Note that that awk one will not necessarily be faster than `LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -c` (in my tests on a 5400000 lines file, 650644 unique, on a GNU system, it isn't) and may use-up the memory and/or reach a limitation in `awk` depending on the `awk` implementation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I cannot comment on the quality of certain `awk` implementations but the idea that `awk` which needs memory according to the number of unique lines whereas `sort` has to store the whole file, seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: `sort` works in batches saved in temp files to avoid filling up the memory. It may fill up the tmp filesystem, but it will not cripple the system.

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange the data with `sort` and count the matching occurences using `uniq -c`

```
sort < input.txt | uniq -c
```

Comment: You'll need to force the locale to C for both `sort`  and `uniq` for that to  work properly. Try `printf '%s\n' ① ② | sort | uniq -c` in a typical GNU system deployment for instance.